# Get Azure role assignments based on resource given

Tags: azure, powershell

I often assign roles at the resource group level, but occasionally I receive requests like "I need the same access as my colleague to read servers A, B, and C" so having this script will be handy for future 'expansion'

I'm curious if there's a way for me to query multiple Azure resources' resource groups in bulk and then display the access permissions that a reference account has. This would include whether the access is at the resource group, subscription, or management group level.

Any guidance you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

This would be something I hope to achieve if this makes any sense...

```
Resource ResourceGroup  Subs          MG  Scope       Role(s)
ServerA  ResourceGroup1 Subscription1 MG1 Direct      XXX-Role
ServerB  ResourceGroup2 Subscription2 MG1 Group       XXX-Role
ServerC  ResourceGroup3 Subscription3 MG2 MgmtGroup   XXX-Role
```

This is my draft currently. It's rough, but I am having difficulty getting anything that is on the management group level:

```
#### PART ONE: Get RG of resources ####

# Define the list of VM names
$vmNames = @(
    "eusql41", "euapp41", "eusql81", "euapp81"
)

# Retrieve all available contexts
$contexts = Get-AzContext -ListAvailable

# Initialize an array to hold the results
$results = @()

# Iterate over each context
foreach ($context in $contexts) {
    # Set the current context
    Set-AzContext -Subscription $context.Subscription

    # Iterate over each VM name and retrieve its resource group
    foreach ($vmName in $vmNames) {
        # Query Azure for the VM
        $vm = Get-AzVM -Name $vmName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

        # Add VM details to the results array only if VM exists
        if ($vm -ne $null) {
            $results += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                VMName = $vm.Name
                ResourceGroup = $vm.ResourceGroupName
                Subscription = $context.Subscription
                Context = $context
            }
        }
    }
}

# Sort results by Resource Group and then VM Name
$sortedResults = $results | Sort-Object ResourceGroup, VMName

# Output the sorted results
$sortedResults | Format-Table -Property VMName, ResourceGroup, Subscription

#### PART TWO: Get Target's assignment ####

# Iterate over the sorted results
foreach ($result in $sortedResults) {
    $vmName = $($result.VMName)
    $resourceGroup = $($result.ResourceGroup)
    $subscriptionId = $result.Subscription
    $context = $result.Context

    Write-Host "Checking $vmName in $($SubscriptionId.Id)" -ForegroundColor Yellow

    # Set the context for the current iteration
    Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $($SubscriptionId.Id)
    $current = Get-AzContext 
    Write-Host "Now in $current"
    # Get role assignments for the user in the specific resource group
    $roleAssignments = Get-AzRoleAssignment -SignInName 'john@contoso.com' -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    # Check if there are any role assignments
    if ($roleAssignments) {
        foreach ($roleAssignment in $roleAssignments) {
            # Determine the access type based on ObjectType
            if ($roleAssignment.ObjectType -eq 'User') {
                $accessType = 'Direct'
            } elseif ($roleAssignment.ObjectType -eq 'Group') {
                $accessType = 'Group'
            } else {
                $accessType = 'Unknown'
            }

            # Prepare the output object
            $output = [PSCustomObject]@{
                VMName = $vmName
                ResourceGroup = $resourceGroup
                Subscription = $subscriptionId
                AccessType = $accessType
                Role = $roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionName
            }

            # Output the details
            Write-Output $output
        }
    } else {
        Write-Output "No role assignments found for john@contoso.com in $resourceGroup"
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of assigning roles to inviduals, assign roles to groups. You can then add member to / remove members from that group so they have the same set of permissions

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Peter Bons's comment, Assigning roles to groups instead of individuals can simplify the management of access permissions. You can add or remove members from the group to grant or revoke access to resources.

Here is the sample command to assign a role (Virtual Machine Contributor) to the groups:

**Command:**

```
New-AzRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName "Virtual Machine Contributor" -ObjectId <group_object_id> -ResourceGroupName <resource_group_name>
```

You can get the group object ID from the portal or PowerShell.

**Portal:**

[image]

**PowerShell:**

```
$groupid=(Get-AzADGroup -DisplayName <groupName>).id
```

**Output:**

```
$grpname="samplegroup1"
PS /home/xxx> $groupid=(Get-AzADGroup -DisplayName $grpname).id
PS /home/xxx> $groupid
1d9589f0-d67e-401d-a32xxxxx
```

To add or remove the group member, you can use the commands below:

**For adding a member:**

```
$uname="xxxx"
$member=(Get-AzADUser -DisplayName $uname).Id
Add-AzADGroupMember -TargetGroupObjectId $groupid -MemberObjectId $member
```

**For removing a member:**

```
$uname="xxxx"
$member=(Get-AzADUser -DisplayName $uname).Id
Remove-AzADGroupMember -TargetGroupObjectId $groupid -MemberObjectId $member
```

The above process will add your role assignment to a particular group, and you can also add or remove members from the group to grant or revoke access to resources.

**Reference:**

[Assign Azure roles using Azure PowerShell - Azure RBAC | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-powershell#step-1-determine-who-needs-access)